# is it possible to differentiate between string and enum of strings in typescript?

Tags: typescript

so I have

```
type newType = ResourcesKey | string;

enum ResourcesKey {    
    FirstString= 'path',
    ...
    }
```

I then have a function that takes the instance and I want to test if it's a string or an enum, but in typescript are the two considered the same?

```
Function(instance: newType)
{
   if (instance instanceof ResourcesKey) {

   }
}
```

this returns an error 
error TS2359: The right-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any' or of a type assignable to the 'Function' interface type.

is there anything I can do to compare the instance to the type of the enum?

for example in C# I would probably be able to do something like

```
if (typeof (instance) == ResourcesKey) {
}
```

I can work around it of course, but I'm wondering what the preferred course of action is

Comment: No, here enum values are just strings. If you want to check if `instance` is one of enum values, you can go with something like `Object.values(ResourcesKey).includes(instance)`

Comment: is there a reason why instanceof doesn't work either?

shouldn't it check to see whether the instance has the prototype property of the String constructor inside the prototype chain of the instance?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: You should look at transpiled code (javascript). At runtime enum values are regular strings

Answer (score 1):

`instanceof` would just work for classes anyway so you can't use it with an enum.

A runtime enums are just string, so testing for this means actually testing if the string value is in the enum. You can create a custom typeguard that will do the check and inform the compiler of the type:

```
type newType = ResourcesKey | string;

enum ResourcesKey {
    FirstString = 'path',

}

function isResourceKey(o: newType): o is ResourcesKey {
    return Object.keys(ResourcesKey).some(k => ResourcesKey[k as keyof typeof ResourcesKey] === o);
}

function doStuff(instance: newType) {
    if (isResourceKey(instance)) {
        console.log(`Res: ${instance}`) // instance: ResourcesKey
    } else {
        console.log(`Str: ${instance}`) // instance: string 
    }
}

doStuff("")
doStuff(ResourcesKey.FirstString)
doStuff("path") // still resource
```